# Adding a PHP variable to an array in JSON

Tags: php, json

I am calling a PHP file from an iOS app to validate user login:

```
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST['username'] == $usuariologin && $_POST['password'] == $clavelogin) {
    echo '{"success":1,"idusuario":"'.$id.'"}';


 }
```

The response at the app is:

```
 Response ==> BASE DE DATOS U={"success":1,"idusuario":""}
```

But the value of idusuario ($id in the PHP file) should be 1 and not "".

Any help is welcome....

Comment: Where do you ever define `$id`...?

Comment: Also, don't ever produce JSON by hand. Use `echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'idusuario' => $id))`

Comment: @deceze it is defined in the PHP file: $id = $row50['MemId']; I have echoed the result and it is 1.

Comment: @deceze, I am following a tutorial, and the PHP file there uses this way to produce JSON, but I will try your proposal, thank you.

Comment: We don't see `$id` being defined anywhere. The code you show *cannot* work, we have no indication to the contrary.

Comment: "I am following a tutorial" --- it makes sense to not follow that tutorial anymore since it's stupid.

Comment: @zerkms, I know, this is it http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2013/12/ios-login-screen-tutorial-xcode-5-ios-7-storyboard-json/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

decode the json first

`$data = json_decode($json,true);`

change whatever

`$data['idusuario'] = "some new value";`

encode back into json string

`$json = json_encode($data);`

Comment: It works as you said, thank you...